# Como seria esse código em JQuery no JS puro?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Esse trecho de código é para ativar a classe .nav porém no JS tem algumas opções como:

```
classList.toggle('active-nav')
```

mas e para desativar quando clicar novamente em JS puro?
segue script com Jquery!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active-nav').siblings().removeClass('active-nav');
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente, o Toggle não serve para ativar uma classe. O que ele faz é adicionar uma classe, caso ela não esteja já adicionada. E caso ela já esteja adicionada ele remove ela.

Para remover você usa `.remove('nomeDaClasse')`, e parar adicionar `.add('nomeDaClasse')`.

Adicionei um exemplo abaixo, para você ver na prática como isso funciona:

```js
function trocaClasse() {
  var texto = document.getElementById("texto");
  texto.classList.toggle('ativo');
}

function addClasse() {
  var texto = document.getElementById("texto");
  texto.classList.add('ativo');
}

function removeClasse() {
  var texto = document.getElementById("texto");
  texto.classList.remove('ativo');
}
```

```css
.ativo {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="trocaClasse()">Testar - Toggle</button>
<button onClick="addClasse()">Testar - ADD</button>
<button onClick="removeClasse()">Testar - Remove</button>

<br>

<span id="texto" onClick="trocaClasse()">Clique no texto para trocar a cor</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

Como referiste bem o JavaScript nativo tem o `toggle` que pode ajudar aqui. Uma versão desse código em JavaScript moderno poderia ser assim:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var navs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.nav'));

  function toggle(clicked) {
    return function() {
      navs.forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('active-nav', el == clicked));
    }
  }
  navs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', toggle(el)));
}
```

```css
div.nav {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: #eee;
  transition: background-color .6s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.nav.active-nav {
  background-color: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">A</div>
<div class="nav">B</div>
<div class="nav">C</div>
<div class="nav">D</div>
```

A ideia é usar o segundo argumento do `toggle` para comparar os elementos iterados com o clicado.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução seria:

```js
(function(){
   obj = document.getElementsByClassName("nav");
   for(x=0;x<obj.length;x++){
      (function(index){
         obj[x].addEventListener("click", function(){
            this.className += " active-nav";
            for(j=0;j<obj.length;j++){
               if(index != j) obj[j].classList.remove("active-nav");
            }
         });
      })(x);
   }
})();
```

```css
div{
  display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid #ddd; line-height: 30px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer;
}

.active-nav{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">1</div>
<br />
<div class="nav">2</div>
<br />
<div class="nav">3</div>
```